# What is the benefit of the WebDriver protocol over injected JavaScript automation?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, code-injection

The W3C defines the [WebDriver Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/), which can be used to automate user inputs on web pages within browsers. It can be used with external browser drivers (such as Google Chrome's Chromedriver or the FireFox Gecko Driver), and actions like button presses and hover events (and many more) can be simulated.

However, I could get the same result by just injecting some custom written JavaScript code which directly generates the events and runs them within the web page context. I could for example just create an `MouseEvent` instance and dispatch it to simulate a click event.

I know that the WebDriver protocol is the state-of-the-art approach to browser automation, but why is that so? What are the benefits of using a protocol which requires browser dependent driver software, when I could just open the Webpage and run injected automation code?

I would probably still need external software to open a browser instance and inject the automation code, but I don't see the need for a full browser-external interface for event automation.

Comment: just from the top of my head: e2e testing and web scraping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Jason Huggins started building the Core mode of Selenium (the original one) as `JavaScriptTestRunner` wherein a javascript automation script is injected to the web application to run automation.
- `Same origin policy` was one of the main hurdles for this mode of automation which states that to execute javascript files on a web page, the javascript file should originate from the same domain on which the web page loaded from. For example: to run javascript function from js files on www.google.com page, the javascript files must be downloaded from www.google.com web server itself. The browser prevents the user from injecting a javascript file from outside and executing it.
- So how did Jason do the automation? He included the `JavaScriptTestRunner` in the web application under test.

> Expecting testers to have access to the web server to include the `JavaScriptTestRunner` into the server is not practical. Also, in production servers this is big NO-GO.

- RC and then the WebDriver projects then came about to tackle these issues.

> With WebDriver protocol, a user only needs access to the application under test in a browser to write UI automation. There is no need to have back end server access.
>
> WebDriver architecture is beautifully designed to have 2 objects(primarily) to achieve automation - WebDriver to control the browser and find WebElements and WebElement to perform operations on the application UI.

```
// Open chrome
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
// open url
driver.get("url");
// find element
WebElement someElement = driver.findElement(By.id("some-id"));
// perform operation on element
someElement.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

- no risk of conflicts with other javascript running on the page
- works on resources that are not html pages, have no dom, and won't run javascript
- can access features (eg. browser logs) that injected js does not have permission to run
- flow control is not broken by unexpected page navigation, reload, etc
- easier to deal with switching between tabs, windows, frames when your code isn't running inside one of those frames